# How to use substitute function to decrypt and encrypt messages

Tags: excel, vba

I want to encrypt and decrypt messages by changing the character A to N, and B to O ..like you see in my code. I need some help to to that, thanks!!

```
Sub MacroCryptage()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Feuil1")
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = ws1.Range("G" & 6)
Set cell = ws1.Range("G" & 5)

    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "A", "N")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "B", "O")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "C", "P")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "D", "Q")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "E", "R")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "F", "S")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "G", "T")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "H", "U")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "I", "V")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "J", "W")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "K", "X")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "L", "Y")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "M", "Z")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "N", "A")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "O", "B")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "P", "C")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "Q", "D")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "R", "E")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "S", "F")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "T", "G")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "U", "H")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "V", "I")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "W", "J")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "X", "K")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "Y", "L")
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "Z", "M")

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? :)

Comment: Do you wish to make it shorter or?..

Comment: In your code, a string `ABC` will turn into `NBC` then `NOC`, `NOP`, `AOP`, `ABP` and finally `ABC`. Try scanning thru the string, operate each character one by one.

Comment: I want to return for example : MY NAME => ZL ANZR, and to decrypts in the same sens.

Comment: when crypting or decrypts i want to substitute: A>N, B>O, C>P,...M>Z, and vice versa! it s about splitting alphabet into 13 character and it s like mirror like what you see in the example, hope that its clear

Comment: I tried this but it returns the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that your solution only applies to two specified cells. You should write it as a function that accepts the original text and returns the coded string

What you are looking at is ROT13. The simplest way to implement this is to use the ASCII values of the characters. In VBA you can use the ASC() function to return the ascii value of a char, then add 13 and then use the CHR() function to turn that value back into a character. This version only works on upper case text - characters 65 to 90. Lower case run 97 to 122 so you could add a test for that if you wanted

```
Public Function Cypher(origtext as string) as string
dim s as string
dim answer as string
dim x as integer
dim myvar as integer
for x = 1 to len(origtext)
     s = mid(origtext,x,1)
     myvar = asc(s)+13
     if myvar > 90 then myvar = 65 + (myvar-91) ' 91 maps to 65, etc. Could instead just use myvar = myvar - 26
     s = chr(myvar)
     answer = answer & s
next x
Cypher = answer
End Function
```

To use this, in the spreadsheet enter =Cypher(cell ref) where cell ref contains the text you want to cypher

Comment: thanks for your help, but I don't know how to implement this ! it will be with a button ..?

Comment: No, the code creates a new function you can use in your spreadsheet like SUM or COUNT. Enter the text you want to change in a cell (say A1) and then in another cell enter =cypher(a1)